# Negative numbers in range() function - how to print from positive to negative numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, range

I'm trying to create a function that prints a board with labelled axes. This is my code for printing the y axis.

```
y = [-1, 4]

y_axis = range(y[0], y[1]+1)

for i in y_axis: # rows 
    print(y_axis[i])
```

This is the output that I get:

```
4
-1
0
1
2
3
```

Why does it not start from y[0] and go in integer increments until y[1]+1 ? I thought that was the output of the range() function.
For my project, I need this piece of code to output the following instead:

```
4
3
2
1
0
-1
```

I don't understand how to get my desired result, I've been trying for hours! Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Edit: the tricky part is that this should be able to print in the correct order any kind of range: if I use a negative step it might not work correctly for all positive values etc
A method like this doesn't work:
-1 -> 4: range(y[0], y[1]+1)
4 -> -1: range(y[1], y[0]-1, -1)

I need a universal solution. could it have to do with the enumerate() function?

Comment: `print(i)` instead of `print(y_axis[i])`

Comment: If you want `range()` to produce a descending sequence, you have to pass the optional third parameter (`step`) with a negative value.

Comment: ^Correct. You are using the value of the range as the INDEX of the range as well.

Comment: Also note that you need BOTH the fixes in not_speshal's and jasonharper's comments to get the desired output - it is not either/or.

Comment: Just for clarity: to  get -1 -> 4: `range(y[0], y[1]+1)`, to get 4 -> -1: `range(y[1], y[0]-1, -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
y = [-1, 4]

y_axis = range(y[1], y[0]-1, -1)

for i in y_axis:
    print(i)
```

There are two problems with your original code:

1. Print should be the element, not indexing the list.
2. Your range should start from 4 (first element) and end at -2 (second element). In order yo make sure you decrement, use the third argument of function range: step. step=-1 decrements from the first element to the last element. You can test the order of the items range outputs by doing:

   print([i for i in range(4, -2, -1)])

Hope this helped! Cheers! :)

Comment: but what if the range was y = [2, 5]? then it would have to be completely different. I was more looking for a universal solution

Comment: My answer reflects the question you asked :)
To answer this second question, you can easily split this into two paths using a conditional. Here:

`y = [bla, bla]

if y[0]<y[1]:
    y_axis = range(y[0], y[1])
if y[0]>y[1]:
    y_axis = range(y[1], y[0]-1, -1)
else:
    raise ValueError(f'The range for the y-axis is zero. Y-axis limits have to be different: {y}')

for i in y_axis:
    print(i)
`
Now you're set with a universal solution. Good luck! If you found my answer helpful, don't hesitate to upvote and Approve as Answer. It would be much appreciated :)